# fabricJS text with uniform lineheight for each line

Tags: html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want the text lines to exactly have the same lineHeights but the first line doesn't have the line height

Please check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fahadnabbasi/zukc6pvc/1/

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var text_temp = new fabric.IText("One Two Three\nFour Five Six\nSeven Eight Nine", {
    left: 20,
    top: 20,
    fontSize: 48,
    fill: "#000000",
    lineHeight : 2
});
        
canvas.add(text_temp)
```

I want it something like this attached image

[image]

Comment: Is the last line that does not have lineHeight. So you can modify to get he last higher, not the first. lineHeight spacing is below text in fabricjs implementation. would that be ok?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi last line has lineHeight applied to it but the problem is first line adds some spacing on top based on font size.

Comment: No the point is that the space is UNDER the text, so all the lines but not the last are using lineHeight. Adding space OVER the text is no possible, it would be easier for you to add space under last line.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi thanks for explanation, is there anyway for me to add the top space? or is there any way the first line always touches the top bounding rect?

Comment: maybe yes. can i ask you a working snippet on stack overflow with a textbox/itext whatever you need?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi is this link not working? https://jsfiddle.net/fahadnabbasi/zukc6pvc/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// override this to get always full line height
fabric.Text.prototype.calcTextHeight = function() {
      var lineHeight, height = 0;
      for (var i = 0, len = this._textLines.length; i < len; i++) {
        lineHeight = this.getHeightOfLine(i);
        height += lineHeight;
      }
      return height;
    };
    
fabric.Text.prototype._getTopOffset = function() {
  return -this.height / 2 + this.getHeightOfLine(0) / this.lineHeight;
};

var text_temp = new fabric.IText("One Two Three\nFour Five Six\nSeven Eight Nine", {
            left: 20,
            top: 20,
            fontSize: 48,
            textBackgroundColor: 'red',
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
            fill: "#000000",
            lineHeight : 2
        });
        
        canvas.add(text_temp)
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

I'm not sure this is a complete solution, nor i want to go deeper in modifying a core behaviour of the library. This snippet can helpyou but can also fail in more advanced use cases.

Comment: wow I am really glad it is working as expected, thanks a million @AndreaBogazzi